# Firing triggers in t-sql to insert and update values in columns of same table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in t-sql which has three columns and data as written below

```
fname  lname  fullname

              Amie Dann
              John Hamm
              Charlie Key
```

I have created this t-sql script to insert data in `fname` and `lname` columns
from `fullname` column of the same table:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[profile] (fname)
LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(name, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', fullname)))) As FName
FROM [dbo].[profile]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[profile] (lname)
LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(' ', fullname)+1, 8000)))As LName
FROM [dbo].[profile]
```

Scripts above inserted the values from `fullname` column to `fname` and `lname` column of the same table. Results are written below:

```
firstname  lastname  fullname

Amie       Dann       Amie Dann
John       Hamm       John Hamm
Charlie    Key        Charlie Key
```

I am new in creating triggers. How to create a trigger which fires and add or updates values in `fname` and `lname` column of the table, whenever anyone either changes any value or add new value
in `fullname` column of the same table?

Answer (score 0):

I would look to a computed column instead of a trigger.

[Link from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

I would suspect your syntax would be:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[profile] ADD [lname] AS LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(' ', fullname)+1, 8000)))
```

I might look at using the LEN function to determine the full lenght needed instead of using the 8000.

Comment: i have to use trigger so that any change in values in "fullname" column should come up in "fname" and "lname" columns with the help of trigger. Trigger should make sure that any update in "fullname" column is represented in other two columns as well.

Comment: cannot use computed columns as none of the columns I mentioned are virtual columns in the table

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use computed columns (the recommendation by John was to actually change the definition of your table to make fname and lname computed columns (persisted) would be even better.  You can then populate fullname and not have to worry about dealing with fname and lname.

e.g.

```
use tempdb
go

create table dbo.Customers(
id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
fname as LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(fullname, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', fullname)))) persisted,
lname as LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(fullname, CHARINDEX(' ', fullname)+1, 8000))) persisted,
fullname varchar(512)
);

insert into dbo.Customers  (Id,fullname) values(1,'Amie Dann');
insert into dbo.Customers  (Id,fullname) values(2,'John Hamm');
insert into dbo.Customers  (Id,fullname) values(3,'Charlie Key');

select * from dbo.Customers
```

Here is a trigger example, notice that i used a instead of trigger so you do not have to perform an an insert/update twice.

```
use tempdb
go

create table dbo.Customers(
id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
fname varchar(256),
lname varchar(256),
fullname varchar(512)
);

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_dbo_Customers
on dbo.Customers
instead of insert,update
AS
begin

    IF exists(select 1 from deleted)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE c
        SET fullname = i.fullname,
            fname = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(i.fullname, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', i.fullname)))),
            lname = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(i.fullname, CHARINDEX(' ', i.fullname)+1, 8000)))
    FROM dbo.Customers c
    INNER JOIN inserted i
        ON i.id = c.id
INNER JOIN deleted d
    ON i.id = d.id
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Customers (id,fullname,fname,lname)
        SELECT
            Id = i.Id,
            fullname = i.fullname,
            fname = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(i.fullname, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', i.fullname)))),
            lname = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(i.fullname, CHARINDEX(' ', i.fullname)+1, 8000)))
        FROM inserted i
            WHERE not exists(select 1 from dbo.Customers c WHERE i.id = c.id)
    END
END
go

insert into dbo.Customers  (Id,fullname) values(1,'Amie Dann');
insert into dbo.Customers  (Id,fullname) values(2,'John Hamm');
insert into dbo.Customers  (Id,fullname) values(3,'Charlie Key');

select * from dbo.Customers
```

Comment: thanks. One issue though. My fullname column can have hundreds of values and not just 3 values that i mentioned. So using statements like  insert into dbo.Customers  (Id,fullname) values(1,'Amie Dann');
insert into dbo.Customers  (Id,fullname) values(2,'John Hamm');
insert into dbo.Customers  (Id,fullname) values(3,'Charlie Key'); is appropriate????? can we change that to something generic?  I am also using table with twenty columns. I only mentioned 3 columns as trigger suppose to act only on these 3 columns

Comment: Sorry, I didnt clarify.  All of the table and insert is there just for a sample.  Essentially i just wanted to show you how a complete solution may look.  All you really need to implement is the trigger code with your table/column names.  You can then run updates or inserts against your table and the fname and lname will populate.

Comment: ok. So if I have an actual table with twenty columns including these 3 columns, I should implement this trigger with all 20 column names in the table? Am I correct?

Comment: No just add the remaining columns to the trigger.  You need to add them to the update statement and the insert statement.

Comment: ok so only this part to implement with my table/column names           CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_dbo_Customers
on dbo.Customers
instead of insert,update
TO UNTIL
        FROM inserted i
    END
END.              Perfect Thanks. I am going to do now

Comment: After implementing this trigger, I found out that this trigger is good for update values only, but not good for insert values as with insert script it creates the duplicate value, so won't let you do insert. Do we need to add delete anywhere?

Comment: I implemented your insert statement to test and I got this error "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object '' with unique index '' "  So insert is not proper in the code. Any solution?